# addplot3[surf] creates lines instead of a surface

Tags: pgfplots

I have been trying to create a surface plot but I am unable to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried using `surf` which only produces lines instead of a surface (Fig. 1). Note: Although I was originally able to produce output, the`surf` plot no longer compiles: "Package tikz Error". I've tried compiling with both pdflatex and lualatex with -shell-escape flag.

[image]

Figure 1

I also tried to use the `patch` style plot. This produces gibberish (Fig. 2)

[image]

Figure 2

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering

  \tikzsetnextfilename{surface_plot}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
      height=12cm,
      width=15cm,
      grid=major,
      grid style={dotted},
      colormap/jet,
      mesh/ordering=x varies
    ]
      %\addplot3[patch,patch type=biquadratic,shader=faceted interp,patch refines=3] coordinates {
      \addplot3[surf] coordinates {

(-6,-6,446.788)  (-5,-6,423.361)  (-4,-6,413.264)  (-3,-6,402.349)  (-2,-6,388.948)  (-1,-6,391.747)  (0,-6,386.874)  (1,-6,423.778)  (2,-6, 439.19)  (3,-6,449.074)  (4,-6,462.155)  (5,-6,484.399)  (6,-6,505.412)
(-6,-5, 423.48)  (-5,-5,392.382)  (-4,-5,406.696)  (-3,-5,392.592)  (-2,-5,371.158)  (-1,-5,384.142)  (0,-5,394.666)  (1,-5,408.105)  (2,-5, 422.51)  (3,-5,420.173)  (4,-5,445.816)  (5,-5,464.731)  (6,-5,485.349)
(-6,-4,402.646)  (-5,-4,371.879)  (-4,-4,376.239)  (-3,-4,396.874)  (-2,-4,382.761)  (-1,-4,386.665)  (0,-4,397.148)  (1,-4,410.875)  (2,-4,425.998)  (3,-4,385.143)  (4,-4,420.458)  (5,-4,438.432)  (6,-4,    458)
(-6,-3,423.219)  (-5,-3,370.582)  (-4,-3,464.786)  (-3,-3,443.921)  (-2,-3,425.196)  (-1,-3,427.138)  (0,-3,438.002)  (1,-3, 453.97)  (2,-3,473.021)  (3,-3,418.583)  (4,-3,435.887)  (5,-3,414.993)  (6,-3,475.148)
(-6,-2,401.995)  (-5,-2,385.612)  (-4,-2,438.956)  (-3,-2,418.583)  (-2,-2,400.093)  (-1,-2,400.773)  (0,-2, 410.58)  (1,-2,426.024)  (2,-2, 444.92)  (3,-2,397.131)  (4,-2,413.739)  (5,-2,431.741)  (6,-2,451.267)
(-6,-1,382.978)  (-5,-1,335.274)  (-4,-1,416.598)  (-3,-1,396.718)  (-2,-1,378.348)  (-1,-1,377.455)  (0,-1,32.0089)  (1,-1,400.683)  (2,-1,419.918)  (3,-1,377.371)  (4,-1,393.286)  (5,-1,374.648)  (6,-1,429.077)
(-6, 0,365.902)  (-5, 0,350.965)  (-4, 0,397.527)  (-3, 0, 378.36)  (-2, 0,360.454)  (-1, 0,358.447)  (0, 0,    363)  (1, 0,381.147)  (2, 0,401.177)  (3, 0,362.155)  (4, 0,378.174)  (5, 0,395.513)  (6, 0, 414.34)
(-6, 1,372.511)  (-5, 1,326.945)  (-4, 1,407.215)  (-3, 1,388.646)  (-2, 1,371.945)  (-1, 1,371.003)  (0, 1,380.027)  (1, 1,396.414)  (2, 1,416.602)  (3, 1,374.897)  (4, 1,391.276)  (5, 1, 373.32)  (6, 1,428.284)
(-6, 2,391.149)  (-5, 2,376.191)  (-4, 2,406.941)  (-3, 2,369.633)  (-2, 2,393.583)  (-1, 2,394.184)  (0, 2,404.263)  (1, 2,420.588)  (2, 2,  440.5)  (3, 2,416.631)  (4, 2,374.948)  (5, 2,391.855)  (6, 2,418.511)
(-6, 3,375.967)  (-5, 3,361.698)  (-4, 3,357.421)  (-3, 3,368.273)  (-2, 3,377.106)  (-1, 3,378.664)  (0, 3,369.175)  (1, 3, 382.42)  (2, 3,397.821)  (3, 3,377.942)  (4, 3,384.944)  (5, 3,387.862)  (6, 3,424.429)
(-6, 4,396.478)  (-5, 4,381.554)  (-4, 4,376.162)  (-3, 4,388.843)  (-2, 4,375.881)  (-1, 4,378.384)  (0, 4, 355.14)  (1, 4,403.654)  (2, 4,419.779)  (3, 4,398.599)  (4, 4,407.113)  (5, 4,426.715)  (6, 4,448.245)
(-6, 5,409.364)  (-5, 5,380.492)  (-4, 5,387.843)  (-3, 5,360.034)  (-2, 5, 362.23)  (-1, 5,364.909)  (0, 5,358.321)  (1, 5,363.226)  (2, 5,379.325)  (3, 5,397.152)  (4, 5,410.086)  (5, 5,433.909)  (6, 5,460.548)
(-6, 6, 423.99)  (-5, 6,408.967)  (-4, 6,400.475)  (-3, 6,372.922)  (-2, 6,371.116)  (-1, 6, 373.92)  (0, 6,384.778)  (1, 6,  398.8)  (2, 6, 415.62)  (3, 6,420.127)  (4, 6,436.064)  (5, 6,461.957)  (6, 6,491.123)

      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}     
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: I recommend switching to table format instead coordinates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PGFPlots needs to know how many coordinates are in each row of data. With the formatting you're currently using, it can't infer this information, since it only sees one long line of coordinates (the line breaks aren't enough to break the sequence).

To make the plot work correctly, you can either

- set `mesh/cols=13`
- set `mesh/rows=13`
- add an empty line after the first line of data

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering

  \tikzsetnextfilename{surface_plot}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
      height=12cm,
      width=15cm,
      grid=major,
      grid style={dotted},
      colormap/jet,
      mesh/ordering=x varies,
      mesh/cols=13
    ]
      \addplot3[surf] coordinates {
(-6,-6,446.788)  (-5,-6,423.361)  (-4,-6,413.264)  (-3,-6,402.349)  (-2,-6,388.948)  (-1,-6,391.747)  (0,-6,386.874)  (1,-6,423.778)  (2,-6, 439.19)  (3,-6,449.074)  (4,-6,462.155)  (5,-6,484.399)  (6,-6,505.412)
(-6,-5, 423.48)  (-5,-5,392.382)  (-4,-5,406.696)  (-3,-5,392.592)  (-2,-5,371.158)  (-1,-5,384.142)  (0,-5,394.666)  (1,-5,408.105)  (2,-5, 422.51)  (3,-5,420.173)  (4,-5,445.816)  (5,-5,464.731)  (6,-5,485.349)
(-6,-4,402.646)  (-5,-4,371.879)  (-4,-4,376.239)  (-3,-4,396.874)  (-2,-4,382.761)  (-1,-4,386.665)  (0,-4,397.148)  (1,-4,410.875)  (2,-4,425.998)  (3,-4,385.143)  (4,-4,420.458)  (5,-4,438.432)  (6,-4,    458)
(-6,-3,423.219)  (-5,-3,370.582)  (-4,-3,464.786)  (-3,-3,443.921)  (-2,-3,425.196)  (-1,-3,427.138)  (0,-3,438.002)  (1,-3, 453.97)  (2,-3,473.021)  (3,-3,418.583)  (4,-3,435.887)  (5,-3,414.993)  (6,-3,475.148)
(-6,-2,401.995)  (-5,-2,385.612)  (-4,-2,438.956)  (-3,-2,418.583)  (-2,-2,400.093)  (-1,-2,400.773)  (0,-2, 410.58)  (1,-2,426.024)  (2,-2, 444.92)  (3,-2,397.131)  (4,-2,413.739)  (5,-2,431.741)  (6,-2,451.267)
(-6,-1,382.978)  (-5,-1,335.274)  (-4,-1,416.598)  (-3,-1,396.718)  (-2,-1,378.348)  (-1,-1,377.455)  (0,-1,32.0089)  (1,-1,400.683)  (2,-1,419.918)  (3,-1,377.371)  (4,-1,393.286)  (5,-1,374.648)  (6,-1,429.077)
(-6, 0,365.902)  (-5, 0,350.965)  (-4, 0,397.527)  (-3, 0, 378.36)  (-2, 0,360.454)  (-1, 0,358.447)  (0, 0,    363)  (1, 0,381.147)  (2, 0,401.177)  (3, 0,362.155)  (4, 0,378.174)  (5, 0,395.513)  (6, 0, 414.34)
(-6, 1,372.511)  (-5, 1,326.945)  (-4, 1,407.215)  (-3, 1,388.646)  (-2, 1,371.945)  (-1, 1,371.003)  (0, 1,380.027)  (1, 1,396.414)  (2, 1,416.602)  (3, 1,374.897)  (4, 1,391.276)  (5, 1, 373.32)  (6, 1,428.284)
(-6, 2,391.149)  (-5, 2,376.191)  (-4, 2,406.941)  (-3, 2,369.633)  (-2, 2,393.583)  (-1, 2,394.184)  (0, 2,404.263)  (1, 2,420.588)  (2, 2,  440.5)  (3, 2,416.631)  (4, 2,374.948)  (5, 2,391.855)  (6, 2,418.511)
(-6, 3,375.967)  (-5, 3,361.698)  (-4, 3,357.421)  (-3, 3,368.273)  (-2, 3,377.106)  (-1, 3,378.664)  (0, 3,369.175)  (1, 3, 382.42)  (2, 3,397.821)  (3, 3,377.942)  (4, 3,384.944)  (5, 3,387.862)  (6, 3,424.429)
(-6, 4,396.478)  (-5, 4,381.554)  (-4, 4,376.162)  (-3, 4,388.843)  (-2, 4,375.881)  (-1, 4,378.384)  (0, 4, 355.14)  (1, 4,403.654)  (2, 4,419.779)  (3, 4,398.599)  (4, 4,407.113)  (5, 4,426.715)  (6, 4,448.245)
(-6, 5,409.364)  (-5, 5,380.492)  (-4, 5,387.843)  (-3, 5,360.034)  (-2, 5, 362.23)  (-1, 5,364.909)  (0, 5,358.321)  (1, 5,363.226)  (2, 5,379.325)  (3, 5,397.152)  (4, 5,410.086)  (5, 5,433.909)  (6, 5,460.548)
(-6, 6, 423.99)  (-5, 6,408.967)  (-4, 6,400.475)  (-3, 6,372.922)  (-2, 6,371.116)  (-1, 6, 373.92)  (0, 6,384.778)  (1, 6,  398.8)  (2, 6, 415.62)  (3, 6,420.127)  (4, 6,436.064)  (5, 6,461.957)  (6, 6,491.123)

      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}     
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```