# How to change this to color map?

Tags: pgfplots, color

Sorry if this question is too basic.

I have the following,

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{h.dat}
0 0 0.0659197583889
1 0 0.0785015007874
2 0 0.176698468088
3 0 0.188451744638
4 0 0.794501652815
5 0 0.797246256151
6 0 0.875537891253
0 1 0.512926531648
1 1 0.104624205858
2 1 0.807266486702
3 1 0.832092257289
4 1 0.965951633102
5 1 0.443549568116
6 1 0.149571282121
0 2 0.909739355463
1 2 0.378099382896
2 2 0.650164271029
3 2 0.450991392221
4 2 0.493981067046
5 2 0.123733424681
6 2 0.450645130458
0 3 0.752902630116
1 3 0.88051943436
2 3 0.0156765163602
3 3 0.343344111644
4 3 0.307406964178
5 3 0.331160200625
6 3 0.159191224462
0 4 0.889020199041
1 4 0.316380353939
2 4 0.456585758376
3 4 0.34330804129
4 4 0.594114167663
5 4 0.452233983882
6 4 0.548585299938
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
               xlabel=$x$,
               ylabel=$y$,
               colorbar,
               colorbar style={
                    title=H,
                    yticklabel style={
                        /pgf/number format/.cd,
                            fixed,
                            fixed zerofill
                    }
               },
               title=Test]
    \addplot3[surf] file {h.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I want is a color map, but I got this.

[image]

Did I miss anything?

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE! Great first MWE.

Comment: You need to set `mesh/cols=7` or add blank lines between your rows. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187091/addplot3surf-creates-lines-instead-of-a-surface/187092#187092

Comment: @Jake, thanks, it is working now, if you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @user200340: I'm glad that the problem is solved. I will close this question as a duplicate of the other one, that will help others with similar questions to find it more easily. Looking forward to seeing you around the site!